# Xamarin.iOS 11 Resources are Not Loaded

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated my instance of Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.3.5 and in the process updated Xamarin.iOS to version 11.0.0.0.

Since updating, several of the resources in my project have stopped working. When deploying to a device, the app icon is not displayed (instead blank icon is shown), and Bundle Resources like a custom font file (.tff) is no longer loading. There has been no code changes to the stable branch of our build, but just updating appears to have broken multiple resources.

Has anyone else encountered this? Does the Xamarin team know about this (I'm looking at you Xamarin folks who said to post my questions in SO)?

EDIT:

Here is the guide for updating an app (doesn't appear to apply to the issue I'm seeing): [Xamarin Update to iOS11](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios11/updating-your-app/).

Here's a specific example of code that has suddenly stopped working despite no code changes:

```
UIFont customFont = UIFont.FromName("streamline-24px", (float)this.IconButton.IconSize);
```

The .tff file is the same, but FromName() yields a null value now.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio foe Mac, resources and custom font is still able to load fine in iOS11.

Comment: What do you mean about "in the process updated"? Has Xamarin.iOS been updated to 11.0.0.0? I test on Visual Studio 15.3.5 and Xamarin.iOS 11 on windows, the icon works well.

Comment: @lowleetak Just to clarify, the issue happens regardless of the iOS being tested on (9, 10, 11), the issue pertains specifically to Xamarin.iOS release 11.

Comment: @Kevin As in Visual Studio Update 15.3.5 included Xamarin.iOS 11, so I thereby installed it Xamarin.iOS 11 by installing VS 15.3.5.
Thanks for the downvote, btw, whoever that was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, hopefully this helps anyone with the same configuration that upgrades their Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS project from Xamarin.iOS release 10 to 11. I was lucky to happen upon it after reading Kevin Mullins answer at [Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48162/why-does-my-app-icon-not-show-up) saying that you should:

> 3. Ensure that all of you icon files are in place (either via the info.pst file or an Image asset).

My Info.plist > Visual Assets looked like this (which worked prior to the update)

[image]

Selecting `Use Asset Catalog` and selecting a value resolved the issue.

[image]